# How to make a table column always use the default value during insertion?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want a timestamp column whose value is always the moment when it's created(specified by the `default current_timestamp` clause), the value client privided is omitted or cause an error.

```sql
create table test
(
  creation_time timestamp default current_timestamp
);

insert into test(creation_time)
values (make_timestamp(1999, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1));
```

```
After exection, the table is:
+----------------------------+
| creation_time              |
| 1999-01-08 01:01:01.000000 |
+----------------------------+
What I want is :
+----------------------------+
| creation_time              |
| 2019-06-09 16:07:01.780816 |
+----------------------------+
```

Comment: If  it's expected to  contain a strictly default value, why is the client allowed to insert values into it? If it's being done through an external program(what's `make_timestamp` ? ), the action should ideally be controlled from there. Although the accepted answer suggests so, Trigger should be your last option for such a simple requirement imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible with a default value.

You should create a trigger that sets the timestamp.

Comment: . . It works fine in Postgres:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=af435b8bc0391f1d25e4fae27b3d4b35

Answer (score 2):

Impaler's method is fine if you have a table with no other columns.  If you do, it is simplest just to leave out the value:

```
insert into test (col)
    values (<value>);
```

Or if you really want to be Postgres specific with no other columns:

```
insert into test
    select;
```

EDIT:

I would suggest that you prevent inserting directly into the table and only allow updated through a view:

```
create view v_test as
    select . . .   -- all columns but the timestamp
    from test;
```

Then only allow updates through the view.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't make it clear that the value should be `current_timestamp` even if I inserted some other value. For example after executing `insert into test(creation_time)
values (make_timestamp(1999, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1));
` I want the column created with value of `current_timestamp`(i.e.2019-06-09...) but not `1999-01-08...`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DEFAULT` keyword, as in:

```
insert into test(creation_time)
values (default);
```

`DEFAULT` is part of the SQL standard.

Comment: @dongjy . . . This would be the best answer if you have no other columns.